# Best way to embed Orbeon 3.9 xform in JSF page

Tags: orbeon

I have been trying for a few days to embed an Orbeon 3.9 supported xform in a JSF page without much luck.  I am running Orbeon as a "separate" deployment (ie. oxf.xforms.renderer.deployment = separate) and if I access an xform directly from the external (non-orbeon) web application everything works fine.  The problem comes when I try to embed that xform inside another web page--which in our case is generated via JSF and facelets.  I am currently trying to use JQuery to load the xform and then call ORBEON.xforms.Init.document(); in the callback method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function () {
         $j("#xform").load("#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/xforms/test.xform?orbeon-embeddable=true", function(data) {
            if (typeof ORBEON != "undefined") { 
                if (!document.all) {
                    ORBEON.xforms.Init.document(); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
   });
</script>
```

When I do this, the page appears to render fine and some of the widgets work properly (e.g. date picker and basic field validation) but none of the widgets which invoke a message box work.  When any widget or event triggers a message box I receive an "Exception in client-side code" error with a detailed message of "Message: Cannot call method 'setBody' of null" (Chrome) or "Message: this._messageDialog is null" (Firefox).

I realize that by using the jQuery load method I am making an ajax call which might not be supported in Orbeon 3.9.  (I have set the oxf.xforms.ajax-portlet to true, just in case this might make a difference; but no such luck.)

I am open to using any method to embed the xform into our JSF/facelet pages, however, I would prefer not to use iframes.  I have experimented with the provided include-form.jsp example and other methods, but this jQuery.load method seemed the most promising--except for this one issue.

UPDATE: I have updated this question further after more research.  I am only receiving this error when a message box is triggered.  Here is a sample HTML page which invokes my xform:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal_web/js/jquery/1.4.2/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var $j = jQuery;

        $j(document).ready(function () {
             $j("#xform").load("/portal_web/xforms/hello.xform?orbeon-embeddable=true", function(data) {
                if (typeof ORBEON != "undefined") { 
                    if (!document.all) {
                        ORBEON.xforms.Init.document(); 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 
       });
    </script>
    <div id="xform">Loading form...please wait...</div>
</body>
```

And, here is a sample xform which exhibits this problem:

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
  xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
<xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:title>Say Hello</xhtml:title>
    <xforms:model>
        <xforms:instance>
            <dummy xmlns=""/>
        </xforms:instance>
    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <xhtml:p>
        <xforms:trigger>
            <xforms:label>Say Hello</xforms:label>
            <xforms:message level="modal" ev:event="DOMActivate">Hello!</xforms:message>
        </xforms:trigger>
    </xhtml:p>
</xhtml:body>
```

This xform should work fine either hosted directly in an Orbeon web application or accessed from a "separate" deployment so long as the xform is accessed directly.  However, if I embed this xform using jQuery (as in the included inline example), the form will render but I will receive an error message when I click on the button (i.e. trigger).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you update your question to provide an example of minimal XForms that we can use to test this? (And also post a follow-up comment here, so I get a notification from StackOverflow.) I have successfully used the technique you described to load the "Hello world" example, and it is working fine. But I imagine that you are using other features in your form.

Comment: avernet, thanks for your comment.  I have updated my question with a sample xform as well as a complete html page which invokes the xform.  (You will need to edit the ""/portal_web/xforms/" part of the html page to suit your environment.)  Thanks!

Comment: You are saying that you only have a problem with an `xforms:message`; is that right? So other XForms features are working OK? For instance, does the vanilla XForms Hello example work for you? I tried here with a message, and it is showing fine. What error are you getting when you click that "Say hello" trigger? And are you getting any error in the JavaScript console before that?

Comment: Yes, I only have a problem with xforms:message.  All other features of my xforms work: e.g. date pickers, field validation, relevancy, etc.  Here's how I can reproduce problem: 1) Download tomcat, 2) drop orbeon.war in webapps directory, 3) create test webapp and drop hello.xform, hello.html, jquery-1.x-min.js, orbeon-xforms-filter.jar in appropriate directories, 4) configure filters in web.xml, 5) add crossContext="true" to context.xml, 6) start tomcat, 7) access hello.xfrom directly works perfectly, 8) access hello.html (with jquery load) displays form but xforms:message fails.

Comment: To answer your question about Javascript errors in the console: on page load and during jquery.load method I see no Javascript errors in the console.  However, when a xforms:message is invoked I see different errors depending on whether you are in Chrome or Firefox.  In Chrome the console error message is "Cannot call method 'setBody' of null"; in Firefox the console error is "Message: this._messageDialog is null".

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned, and can't reproduce the issue. I put the war file I created here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20120201-dynamic.war. Deployed it under `/`, and go to http://localhost:8080/20120201-jquery-load/hello.html to load the example. When I click on the button, the message shows. See: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6900/resources/20120201-dynamic.mov